# Uncaught exception 'TypeError': ImageBuilder::setProduct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2.3, third-party-module, exception-error

I'm seeing the following error log in New Relic. This error logs very rarely, and comes from adding a product to the cart:

> TypeError: Uncaught exception 'TypeError' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder::setProduct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product, null given, called in /srv/public_html/vendor/author/name/Block/Confirm.php on line 417' in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php:55

I'm not sure why this error is logging, this is the block of code in question (Confirm.php, Lines 415 - 421):

```
 public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = [])
 {
    return $this->imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
        ->setImageId($imageId)
        ->setAttributes($attributes)
        ->create();
 }
```

Does anyone see anything out of the ordinary here, that would cause such an error?

Cheers,
Max

Comment: you could check if it is actually a product. `if (!$product instanceof Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) { return false; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php` is declared to use strict types(declare(strict_types=1);) since you do not pass a `Product` but `null` it throws an TypeError. Long story short - you do not pass a `Product` to `getImage`, so check the method call and arguments you pass.